# c# Problems with Localization, CultureInfo Norway and Denmark, translations don't work

Tags: c#, localization, cultureinfo

I am trying to implement language translations of my existing web application.
The application is written in C#, Javascript and Angular JS.

I have successfully added (resx files) and tested the following languages:

-German
-Spanish
-Finnish
-French
-Italian
-Dutch
-Swedish

In the same way, I have also added the resources for Danish and Norwegian, but these fail.

I did the *exact same thing*, at the *exact same time* to implement all of them; I checked all properties and everything else matches.

Is there anything special about these two cultures that might be hindering this?

I called them Translations.no.resx for norwegian and Translations.dk.resx for Danish, and I added the routes accordingly, like this:

```
    private static readonly List<LanguageModel> AllLanguages = new List<LanguageModel>
    {
        new LanguageModel { Name = "English", TwoLetterIsoLanguageName = "en" },
        new LanguageModel { Name = "Svenska", TwoLetterIsoLanguageName = "sv" },
        // ITCR-1182 adding translations. DK and NO are not working.
        new LanguageModel { Name = "Dansk", TwoLetterIsoLanguageName = "dk" },
        new LanguageModel { Name = "Español", TwoLetterIsoLanguageName = "es" },
        new LanguageModel { Name = "Deutsch", TwoLetterIsoLanguageName = "de" },
        new LanguageModel { Name = "Nederlands", TwoLetterIsoLanguageName = "nl" },
        new LanguageModel { Name = "Française", TwoLetterIsoLanguageName = "fr" },
        new LanguageModel { Name = "Norsk", TwoLetterIsoLanguageName = "no" },
        new LanguageModel { Name = "Suomi", TwoLetterIsoLanguageName = "fi" },
        new LanguageModel { Name = "Italiano", TwoLetterIsoLanguageName = "it" }
    };
```

This list is used currently for the language selector, but it will be generated from the database... as soon as I can get them to work!

All language resources are called accordingly:

```
Translations.{TwoLetterIsoLanguageName}.resx
```

Except the english one which is default, Translations.resx

The routes are formed like this

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{culture}/{site}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { culture = LocalizationAttribute.DefaultCulture, site = LayoutController.DefaultSite, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

And as I said, it works for every language except Norwegian and Danish. Or rather, the routes show up as they should, with the "no" or "dk" references, but the translations are not mapping, the default english comes up instead.

Is there something else I can provide, that may help?

Comment: According to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes Danish is da. Norwegian is a little more tricky, since there are two codes nn (nynorsk) and nb (bokmål).

Comment: As @PalleDue said. Additional info: Use bokmål, it is more common (~85%) than nynorsk.

Comment: Thank you @PalleDue, I did exactly as you suggested, da for Danish; and it worked like a charm. I would like to mark your comments as answers, but I can't, since they were posted as comments. Would you like to post again as answer, or shall I post it myself and tag you guys in it?

Comment: Thank you @LocEngineer, I also did as you suggested and went ahead with nb for Norwegian; it worked perfectly! I would also like to tag you as part of the answer, if that is okay?

Comment: No need. @PalleDue can include it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by @PalleDue and @LocEngineer, I was using the wrong two-letter ISO code:

DA for Danish
NN or NB for Norwegian, but better to use NB because it's used by ~85% of the population.

Thank you guys!!!